# Gaussian fit using python

Tags: python, gaussian

Hi and apologies if this is a noob question. I am new to python. I am trying to fit a Gaussian curve on my dataset and I am not sure where I am going wrong. I am following some examples that I found online, but it is not working. Please check the image to see what is happening in the output.

[image: fit is just coming as straight line]
I have my data in excel, and I imported it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\B.d\Documents\interpolate, matplotlib and other example tutorials\ExtendedAxialString4.csv')

x =df.iloc[:,0] #position

y =df.iloc[:,1]   #value 

#then for the gaussian

n = len(x)

mean = sum(x*y)/n                  

sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n       


def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):

    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=[1,mean,sigma])

#plt.title('Gaussian fit,  $f(x) = A e^{(-(x-x_0)^2/(2sigma^2))}$')


plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')

plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')

plt.legend()

plt.title('Fig. 3 - Axial deformation')

plt.xlabel('numbering')

plt.ylabel('deformation(mm)')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please format your code. Please post your complete code.

Comment: Which library did you use for `curve_fit`?

Comment: @gspr apologies, how do i format codes, i copied and pasted my codes but it doesnot work.

Comment: @VigneshPillay import pylab as plb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp
import pandas as pd

Comment: @VigneshPillay, i think i am on the wrong side of the math equation, probably should be looking into 6th order polynomial or something like that

Comment: If you set `p0=[-1,mean,sigma]` you may get  may reasonable answer. I believe curve_fit does local search of parameters. And in such case the best you can get is zero constant. You data are negative the fitting function is positive (taking into account local change of parameters).

Comment: @AskoldIlvento i tried with negative, it is stil producing linear line in the graph but at -1